# Set button invisible for the defined scenario programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have two buttons in a layout and placed horizontally next to each other. I want to hide first button and place the second button in center of the linearlayout.
I have used below code but it doesnt fullfil the requirement.

```
if (flag){

  btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE); //.setEnabled(false);

  android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f);
  params.setMargins(15, 0, 15, 0);

  btn2.setLayoutParams(params);
 }else{
  btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Please suggest.
Thanks.

In xml file both buttons should be horizontally next to each other, incase of hiding one button the second should be horizontally center. and also I am using linearlayout.

Comment: why don't you set this in your xml and just control the visibility dynamically.

Comment: the `else` code will never be called...

Comment: i hav just updated code

Answer (score 0):

Keep xml file and call that button in your activity and setVisibility instead of creating layout dynamically

Comment: problem is not of set the button visible or invisible.how to place button center of layout at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In Activity

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

if (flag){

   btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   parent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

 }else{

 btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 parent.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```